# Какие отношения между таблицами Laravel лучше использовать в данном случае?

Tags: laravel

Таблица `Profiles`:

```
id name:
1 Olga,
2 Marina,
3 Zina
```

Таблица `Languages`:

```
id title
1 Немецкий,
2 Русский
```

Как правильно реализовать связи между таблицами если в `Profile` нам нужно получить не просто язык Немецкий,Русский или оба вместе для каждого профиля но и уровень от 1-6?

Нужно ли создать таблицу `Level` и привязать к `Languages` или как правильнее?

В профиле выбирается язык и его уровень. Сохранять всё в одну или разные таблицы?

То есть с `HTML` кода что ниже при выборе к примеру 1 языка
мы получаем Id profile, id Language и Level

Если создать таблицу такую ?

```
profile_id language_id level
1          2           5
```

```html
@foreach(App\Language::all() as $language)
    <div class="form-group  language-block col-md-12 ">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input onchange="language_level(4860,'language');" id="language_{{$language->id}}" class="languages" type="checkbox" name="language[]" value="{{$language->id}}">
            <label class="lang-label" for="language_{{$language->id}}">{{$language->title}}</label>
        </div>

        <div class="lang-radio col-md-1">
          <input type="radio" id="" onchange="language_level(4860,'language');" name="lang-level-{{$language->id}}" value="1" checked="" disabled>
          <label for="">1</label>
       </div>
       <div class="lang-radio col-md-1">
          <input type="radio" id="" onchange="language_level(4860,'language');" name="lang-level-{{$language->id}}" value="2" disabled >
          <label for="">2</label>
       </div>
       <div class="lang-radio col-md-1">
          <input type="radio" id="" onchange="language_level(4860,'language');" name="lang-level-{{$language->id}}" value="3" disabled>
          <label for="">3</label>
       </div>
       <div class="lang-radio col-md-1">
          <input type="radio" id="" onchange="language_level(4860,'language');" name="lang-level-{{$language->id}}" value="4" disabled>
          <label for="">4</label>
       </div>
       <div class="lang-radio col-md-1">
          <input type="radio" id="" onchange="language_level(4860,'language');" name="lang-level-{{$language->id}}" value="5" disabled>
          <label for="">5</label>
       </div>
       <div class="lang-radio col-md-1">
          <input type="radio" id="" onchange="language_level(4860,'language');" name="lang-level-{{$language->id}}" value="6" disabled>
          <label for="">6</label>
       </div>

    </div>
@endforeach
```

Спасибо

Comment: Я бы реализовал в виде 3 таблиц. Моё решение основано исключительно на том, что написано в вопросе. Такой подход будет лучше, так как завтра вас могут попросить добавить подуровни и ранги и т.п.

Comment: т.е добавить
табл. Level :
id title
1 1,
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6

Comment: Что значит `title`?

Comment: первая цифра это id а title это параметрер в данном случае это тоже цифра

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы разделил на 5 таблицы:

1. `Profiles` - непосредственно профиль пользователя;
2. `Languages` - доступные языки в системе;
3. `Levels` - доступные уровни;
4. `Language Levels` - уровни знания языка;
5. `Profile Languages` - взаимосвязь между пользователем языком и его уровнем.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Модель `Profile`:

```php
class Profile extends Model {

  /**
   * @return HasMany
   */
  public function profile_languages(): HasMany {
    return $this->hasMany(ProfileLanguage::class);
  }

  /**
   * @return HasManyThrough
   */
  public function languages(): HasManyThrough {
    return $this->HasManyThrough(LanguageLevel::class,ProfileLanguage::class,  'profile_id', 'id', 'id', 'language_level_id');
  }

}
```

Модель `LanguageLevel`

```php
class LanguageLevel extends Model {

  /**
   * @return HasOne
   */
  public function language(): HasOne{
    return $this->HasOne(Language::class, 'id', 'language_id');
  }

  /**
   * @return HasOne
   */
  public function level(): HasOne{
    return $this->HasOne(Level::class, 'id', 'level_id');
  }

}
```

Пример выборки: `App\Profile::with('languages.level')->find(1)` и её результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: doox911@спасибо

Comment: если по вашей схеме, 
то
как теперь получить все languages с level к каждому language и все относящиеся к конкретному profile

в конечном счете мне нужно вставить в таблицу в какую-то id profile id Language и id level и также получить их при чтении чтобы показать на странице какие языки уже выбраны

Comment: когда я создал модель с миграцией LanguageLevelProfile
оно создало таблицу language_level_profiles
в профиле указал public function language_level_profile(){
        
        return $this->hasMany(LanguageLevelProfile::class);
    }

Comment: вот я когда обращаюсь
$Profile->language_level_profile

получаю
Languages [{"id":1,"language_id":"1","level_id":"2","profile_id":"1","created_at":null,"updated_at":null}]

Comment: @Junior обновил ответ.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: А можно еще вопрос

Comment: получается данные я получаю обращаясь к двум таблицам profile_languages и language_levels
@foreach($dataTypeContent->languages as $language)
    {{$language->language->title}}
@endforeach

Comment: а чтобы сохранять в них значения как правильно?я через ajax получаю id_profile, id_language, и количество level

Comment: @Junior Вам необходимо сохранять сразу две модели. Сначала `LanguageLevel` а затем взяв у `LanguageLevel` `id` сохранить `ProfileLanguage`

Comment: спасибо !!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: все сделал, но это подтянуло еще проблему)
как проверить что такая строка уже существует в БД laravel, ?
вот я тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1154523/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d0%91%d0%94-laravel спросил

Answer (score 0):

Если пользоваться стандартами Laravel, то здесь вырисовывается следующая схема:

`Profiles` -> `Languages` -> `manyToMany`
`Languages` -> `Levels` -> `manyToMany` (но это необязательная связь, при втором решении).

Тут соответственно напрашиваются уже 5 таблиц:

1. profiles
2. languages
3. levels
4. language_level поля id, language_id, level_id
5. language_user (по алфавиту наименование) с полями profile_id, language_level_id

Но это, если следовать всем нормальным формам БД и соблюдать атомарность таблиц.

Есть и второй вариант с 4 таблицами:

1. profiles
2. languages
3. levels
4. language_user с полями profile_id, language_id, level_id

Но второй вариант подразумевает "хвостик" во всех запросах `withPivotParams`, иначе не будет браться `level_id`

Ну а так решать Вам)

Comment: radar4ick@спасибо

Comment: Вот это 
language_level поля id, language_id, level_id
 я сделал так:
php artisan make:migration create_language_level_table

Comment: связь утановил
Languages -> Levels -> manyToMany

Comment: А вот эту таблицу мы то не связывали?
language_user (по алфавиту наименование) с полями profile_id, language_level_id

Comment: Можно добавить связь, только у profile как hasMany.

Comment: а как мы ее свяжем? если созадать  php artisan make:model LanguageUser -m оно создасть таблицу во множественном числе language_users и это же не будет уже pivit Table ?

Чтобы потом в профиле сделать
public function language_users()
    {
      return $this->hasMany('App\LanguageUser');
    }