# как проверить что такая строка уже существует в БД laravel,

Tags: php, laravel

Сразу вставка идет в таблицу language_levels но а потом в profile_languages
так вот получается что если такой самый (language_id от одного и того же  profile_id передать он снова продублируется

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
foreach ($result as $resul){
                
                $language_level_id = DB::table('language_levels')->insertGetId(
                        ['language_id' => $language_id, 'level_id' => $level_id]);
                
                DB::table('profile_languages')->insert(
                    ['profile_id' => $profile_id, 'language_level_id' => $language_level_id]
                );
            }
```

есть идея но это не костыль будет?

```
1)зная profile_id получить все language_level_id которые пренадлежать данному профилю из таблицы profile_languages,
2)перебирая все id из language_levels и сравнивать language_id c с тем который мы хотим вставить и на сопадении его update если нет то вставить такую строку?
```

Спасибо

Comment: Судя по вопросу, вам не надо проверять, что такая строка уже есть. Вы просто не поняли структуру БД из прошлого своего вопроса.

Comment: @doox911 можете подсказать еще уже на финише) в общем все сделал
осталось только выво в шаблоне что не так может по другому нужно

в общем я в blade.php перебираю все языки, и мне нужно узнать относится этот язык к данному профилю или нет, если да то отмеячаю галкой, если нет пропускаю 
foreach(App\Language::all() as $language)
endforeach

спасибо!

Comment: @doox911 
если что я тут спросил еще https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1155626/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5-languagescollect-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%be-language-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы сохранить запись напишите следующее(на примере `Request $request`):

```php
$language_level =  new LanguageLevel;

$language_level->level_id = $request->level_id;
$language_level->language_id = $request->language_id;

$language_level->save();

$profile_language = new ProfileLanguage;

$$profile_language->profile_id = $request->profile_id;
$profile_language->language_level_id = $language_level->id;
$profile_language-save();
```

Правильно разделять логику создания и обновления модели. Но если вам так хочется, то вот проверка:

Вам необходимо вытащить все языки профиля (приводил пример [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1152586/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-laravel-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5/1152860#1152860)):

```php
App\Profile::with('languages.language')->find($request->profil_id);
```

Затем в выборке найти необходимый язык. Если он есть, обновляем иначе создаём.

Comment: спасибо,
$language_level =  new LanguageLevel;

        $language_level->level_id = '1';
        $language_level->language_id = '1';

        $language_level->save();

        $profile_language = new ProfileLanguage;

        $profile_language->profile_id = $profile_id;
        $profile_language->language_level_id = $language_level->id;
        
        $profile_language->save();

вот если я отправлю один и то самый язык он снова добавится в базу, а нужно же что если он есть то эту строку редактировать т.е поменялся к примеру level у языка а язок то есть

Comment: Так вы создайте `crud`(ресурс) контроллер. И разделите методы редактирование и обновление.

Comment: т.е $request->language я получаю там 1:1|2:3|3:5 //первая цифра это id language, вторая level_id

Comment: Так разные запросы должны идти. При создании, например это `put`.

Comment: а на обюновлоение тьак каждую модель что и сохраняли?
$language_level->update(['name' => 'abc', 'location' => 'xyz']);
$$profile_language->update(['name' => 'abc', 'location' => 'xyz']);

Comment: Обновил ответ..

Comment: большое спасибо!!

Answer (score 0):

Есть у Laravel такая замечательная функция как `exists()`

Пример использования:

`DB::table('orders')->where('finalized', 1)->exists()`

Возвращает `true` или `false`

Comment: спасибо вы смотрели что у меня не простая строка а сразу проверить нужно в двух таблицах

Comment: Так и сделайте 2 проверки сразу

Comment: Сначала сохранить нужно LanguageLevel а затем взяв у LanguageLevel id сохранить ProfileLanguage, а при в ставке я имею только id profile ,id  Language,  Leve_id

Comment: есть идея но это не костыль будет?

1)зная profile_id получить все language_level_id которые пренадлежать данному профилю из таблицы profile_languages,
2)перебирая все id из language_levels и сравнивать language_id c с тем который мы хотим вставить и на сопадении его update если нет то вставить такую строку?

Comment: @Junior после сохранения `LanguageLevel` возьмите у неё `id`.  Мне кажется, что вам лучше моделями работать.

Comment: или нужно другую структуру таблиц делать?